# How to display default value of a select list in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, list, select, modal-dialog, oracle-apex

I want to display the default value of a select list in a modal page without have to click on the select list. I mean, before clicking on the select list it shows a whitespace but I want to show the default value instead.

Thanks for your help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBwxr.png)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to set its default value. Did you?

Apart from that, set Select List item's **Display Null value** property to **No**. It'll prevent that *whitespace* you've mentioned to be displayed.

Comment: I already set the default value and I did what you said but now it does not show anything neither the white spice nor the default value

Comment: If possible, create an example on apex.oracle.com, provide credentials so that we could see what you did.

Comment: Maybe I forgot to mention that the select list is inside a modal page. Is there any difference?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there shouldn't be any difference regarding that issue.

Comment: I've just created a sample interactive grid and set default value for the select list item - works OK; when I push the "Add row" button, default value is visible on the screen. Working with Apex 5.1

Comment: That's right. The problem is when the modal dialog page is open, it does not show the default value until you double click on the select list

Comment: Hm, that's strange ... I created a modal page, set select list's default value and - it still works OK. I have no idea what might be wrong in your case ...